# Creating a Carousel in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I am trying to create a Carousel using JS. I have succeeded a bit and I able to move one slide to the right side. I figure if I somehow increase the value of widthToMove variable then by clicking on right arrow button will keep pushing the slides. I tried to create a function that returns simply 1, 2, 3, and so on and multiply it with widthToMove on clicking right arrow button but I could not succeed. Any help will highly be appreciated.
Here is the html code;

```js
var productDataWomens = [
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/coats-jackets/dark-grey-faux-fur-longline-coat/p/619712403',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/619712403.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Dark Grey Faux Fur Longline Coat',
    price: '45.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/tops/black-ribbed-long-sleeve-roll-neck-top/p/635105501',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/635105501.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black Ribbed Long Sleeve Roll Neck Top',
    price: '8.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/leggings/black-coated-leather-look-leggings/p/634018201',
    imageSrc: 'https://media3.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/634018201.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black Coated Leather-Look Leggings',
    price: '19.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/coats-jackets/black-faux-fur-longline-coat/p/619712401',
    imageSrc: 'https://media3.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/619712401.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black Faux Fur Longline Coat',
    price: '45.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/jeans/black-high-waist-super-skinny-hallie-jeans/p/635654901',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/635654901.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black High Waist Super Skinny Hallie Jeans',
    price: '25.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/coats-jackets/formal-coats/camel-revere-collar-coat/p/619653214',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/619653214.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Camel Revere Collar Coat',
    price: '35.99',
  }
]



for (i in productDataWomens) {
  var node = document.createElement('LI');

  node.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-list-item' + ' ' + 'current-slide');

  var carouselImg = document.createElement('img');
  carouselImg.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-images');
  carouselImg.src = productDataWomens[i].imageSrc;

  node.appendChild(carouselImg);
  document.getElementById('carousel-list-id').appendChild(node);
}

const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-list-items');
console.log(track);
const slides = Array.from(track.children);
console.log(slides);
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.right-button');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.left-button');

const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

nextButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
  console.log(currentSlide);

  let widthToMove = currentSlide.clientWidth;
  console.log(slides[0]);

  widthToMove = widthToMove + 'px';
  console.log(widthToMove);

  let nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;
  console.log(nextSlide);
  //const amountToMove = nextSlide.style.widthToMove;
  track.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + widthToMove + ')';
  currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
  //nextSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-list-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.carousel-container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-images {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 200px;
}

.carousel-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.right-button {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/88ce2b0d97.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>New Look</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
        <button class="left-button carousel-button"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <div class="carousel-container" >
            <ul class="carousel-list">
                <a href="" id="carousel-list-id" class="carousel-list-items">
                     <!-- <li class="carousel-list-item current-slide" id="carousel-list-id"></li> -->
                </a>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        <button class="right-button carousel-button"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your slider is that each time you click on the next button the `widthToMove` variable is overwritten with `currentSlide.clientWidth`, what you should've done instead is:

1. take `widthToMove` variable outside the scope of the listener
2. on each click add the values of `widthToMove` and `currentSlide.clientWidth` and assign the sum to `widthToMove`

Also when your slider is "initialized", every slide has the class `current-slide` therefore you can't determine which slide is the current.

```js
var productDataWomens = [
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/coats-jackets/dark-grey-faux-fur-longline-coat/p/619712403',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/619712403.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Dark Grey Faux Fur Longline Coat',
    price: '45.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/tops/black-ribbed-long-sleeve-roll-neck-top/p/635105501',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/635105501.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black Ribbed Long Sleeve Roll Neck Top',
    price: '8.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/leggings/black-coated-leather-look-leggings/p/634018201',
    imageSrc: 'https://media3.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/634018201.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black Coated Leather-Look Leggings',
    price: '19.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/coats-jackets/black-faux-fur-longline-coat/p/619712401',
    imageSrc: 'https://media3.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/619712401.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black Faux Fur Longline Coat',
    price: '45.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/jeans/black-high-waist-super-skinny-hallie-jeans/p/635654901',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/635654901.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Black High Waist Super Skinny Hallie Jeans',
    price: '25.99',
  },
  {
    productUrl:
      'https://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/coats-jackets/formal-coats/camel-revere-collar-coat/p/619653214',
    imageSrc: 'https://media2.newlookassets.com/i/newlook/619653214.jpg',
    productTitle: 'Camel Revere Collar Coat',
    price: '35.99',
  }
]



for (i in productDataWomens) {
  var node = document.createElement('LI');
  
  // If it's the first slide add .current-slide
  // The line below uses a turnary operator which is a short if/else statement
  var currentSlide = ( i == 0 ? ' current-slide' : '' );
  
  // Which can be rewritten to this
  //var currentSlide;
  
  //if( i == 0 ) {
  //  currentSlide == ' current-slide';
  //} else {
  //  currentSlide == '';
  //}
  
  

  node.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-list-item' + currentSlide );

  var carouselImg = document.createElement('img');
  carouselImg.setAttribute('class', 'carousel-images');
  carouselImg.src = productDataWomens[i].imageSrc;

  node.appendChild(carouselImg);
  document.getElementById('carousel-list-id').appendChild(node);
}

const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-list-items');

const nextButton = document.querySelector('.right-button');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.left-button');

let widthToMove = 0;


nextButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let currentSlide = track.querySelector('.current-slide');
  let nextSlide;
  
  if( !currentSlide.nextElementSibling ) {
    nextSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-list-item')[0];
    widthToMove = 0;
  } else {
    nextSlide = currentSlide.nextElementSibling;
    widthToMove += currentSlide.clientWidth;
  }
  

  // You can use template literals to create a string with several variables/functions/expressions for speed, convenience and readability
  track.style.transform = `translateX(-${widthToMove + 30}px)`;
  currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
  // Add current-slide class to next slide
  nextSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-list-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.carousel-container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-images {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 200px;
}

.carousel-button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
}

.right-button {
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/88ce2b0d97.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>New Look</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
        <button class="left-button carousel-button"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <div class="carousel-container" >
            <ul class="carousel-list">
                <a href="" id="carousel-list-id" class="carousel-list-items">
                     <!-- <li class="carousel-list-item current-slide" id="carousel-list-id"></li> -->
                </a>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
        <button class="right-button carousel-button"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SohailShams I slightly improved the slider. Take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Its great, can you please help me how can I add the productTitle on the image?